# How to handle the leading 4-byte protocol of tun FD packets when reading tun FD directly in C instead of through packetFlow.readPackets in Swift?

Tags: vpn, tun

In iOS SimpleTunnel VPN demo app, it reads the virtual tun interface through packetFlow.readPackets(). In my case, Swift hands over control to C to move data packets between the tunnel and the virtual tun interface. The tun file descriptor will be sent over from Swift to C through this conversion:

```
let tunFd = self.packetFlow.value(forKeyPath: "socket.fileDescriptor") as! Int32
```

as explained by [spensaurus in this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13503), and also [Dinesh's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914735/difference-b-w-self-packetflow-readbytes-vs-socket-read/54072019#54072019).

But I'm stuck with the issue that there is no internet connection even though VPN is showing activated on the device and logs show that the C code is functioning in moving data packets. Following the idea to remove the leading 4 bytes out of the packets read from tun FD doesn't seem to help.

I realize that Apple support made it clear that the above conversion and the way of using tun FD is not supported. I still want to take this approach because of this seems to be a much easier approach instead of porting a whole C library over which can take a lot more time.

So my questions are: 
1. Stripping off the 4 leading bytes of the tun packets should be done all the time, or just under what conditions? 
2. Is it required to add leading 4 bytes protocol to any packets into tun FD? 
3. Anything else you are doing and I might have missed?

I'd very much appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

With trial and error, I found that stripping the 4 leading bytes after reading, and adding them prior to writing tun FD works.